# How to refer to the upper, flat part of a cliff?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A cliff is basically divided in two parts: the "flat" surface where you stand and then fall. What do you call the former? Here's an example of the desired usage:

> There were two climbers on the cliff: one on the safety of the [...], and
>   the other paralyzed, hanging from a thousand-foot fall.

Comment: An example, Jano, "There were two climbers on the cliff: one on the safety of the [*plateau*], and the other [still on the cliff's *face* and] paralyzed, hanging [*above*] a thousand-foot [*chasm*]."

Comment: This is very topical considering the current ongoing cliff-climbing event. The two aren't related by any chance?

Comment: @Pharap Yes, I'm considering joining a trip to Mount Fuji.

Comment: @janoChen Ah, not what I thought. I thought this was related to the two men climbing El Capitan. Incidentally this article about them uses the word 'summit' to refer to the top of the mountain: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-30824372. Though that probably only applies to mountains.

Comment: Have those two completed that climb yet?

Comment: I rather think going on a trip to Mount Fuji is not a very good idea if your notion of a clifftop is “the ‘flat’ surface where you stand _and then fall_” …

Comment: @LittleEva The link in my comment was an article about them reaching the top, and I believe the article was posted a few hours before I posted that link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for ***clifftop***.

> An area of land at the top of a cliff: *the windswept clifftops* [[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clifftop)

As opposed to *cliffside*:

> the steep side of a cliff or of any abrupt natural incline of considerable size [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cliffside)

---

> [image]
>
> Enjoying the high life! Thrill-seekers living on the edge as they jump on **clifftop** 2,300ft above Norwegian fjord ... with no safety rail
>
> The Trolltunga - or Troll's Tongue in English - sits 700 metres above the Ringedalsvatnet Lake in Southern Norway
>
> [[dailymail.co.uk]](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-2766303/Enjoying-high-life-Thrill-seekers-living-edge-jump-clifftop-2-300ft-Norwegian-fjord-no-safety-rail.html)

Comment: Also I would refer to the actual transition line (where clifftop meets cliffside) as the *lip* of the cliff.

Answer (score 3):

I googled this:

The two parts of a cliff referred to are **the horizontal part** or the **pla·teau** /plaˈtō/ noun: plateau; plural noun: plateaux; plural noun: plateaus 1. an area of relatively level high ground. synonyms: upland, tableland, plain, mesa, highland, coteau 
"a windswept plateau"

And, **the vertical part** is referred to as the **cliff-face** (klɪf feɪs) or just, **the face** *noun* 
the vertical face of a cliff. "People have been banned from climbing the cliff face because it is too dangerous."

Comment: Can you please include the source? Plateaus are flat and elevated landforms but are not necessarily on top of a cliff.

Comment: Plateau is from google.com; cliff-face from thesaurus.com

Comment: And I agree with you @ermanen, that plateau is a generic rather than specific term. Best I could do, though.

Comment: @ermanen, on an unrelated vein: I love your cat vid!

Comment: Hmm if we connect our words, we can say "clifftop plateau" to be more specific :)

Answer (score 3):

A 'clifftop' just refers to any top of a cliff.  A 'plateau' is any flat elevated geologic surface.  An 'overhang' is a portion of a structure or formation that protrudes from the main body and rests such that it is 'overhanging' the ground (hanging above it).  When used in the context of overhanging cliffs, the term 'overhang' refers to the part of the cliff that actually has no direct downward connection to the ground.  I think the word most accurately describing the portion of the type of cliff you are talking about is 'overhang', though if the cliff is strictly vertical 'clifftop' may have to suffice.

Comment: A climber would never be safe on an overhang. Overhang refers to the part of the cliff that is steeper than vertical. (i.e. if you draw a line straight up it goes through the rock, not above it. )

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog yes, but it refers to the whole chunk that's like that.  The ground directly above that point is also part of the overhang, and is probably flat-ish.  You are correct it is not safe to walk on (or near!) an overhang.

Comment: That's not how climbers use the term. You are "above" the overhang once you reach any part of the cliff that is vertical or less above the part that is beyond vertical. Using overhang in the sense you suggest would indicate the writer has little or no knowledge of climbing as a sport.

Answer (score 2):

While clifftop is accurate, it is a word that climbers rarely use. Or at least all the climbers I've ever met in the United States.

Any flat part of the cliff is a "ledge" and the last flat part of the cliff is the "summit ledge". Generally, the summit ledge is where you unrope and the climb is considered to be over. In your example above, a climber would use "summit ledge".

However, that might not convey the exact meaning to a general reader. It depends whether you want to use the jargon of the sport to convey expertise, or to be more widely accessible. Also a summit ledge isn't always the top of the cliff, but everything above that is considered easy and safe enough to travel without a rope.

Answer (score 0):

"mesa" usually refers to the flat part. Mesa means table.

Comment: _Mesa_ is a type of hill and it is the name of the whole formation. It doesn't refer to the flat top of a hill or cliff.

Comment: @ermanen *Mesa* is the type of hill that has a flat top, table-like. In that respect, OP's right – At OP: You should clarify that *mesa* is table in Spanish and Portuguese. It doesn't mean *table* in English.